# how can i access to a property of a model in another model which has a many to many relationship with it (in django)

Tags: python, django

I have a project and in which I need to get access to a property in this case `price` from model `options`,
but I wanna get that in  `order` model which has a Many To Many relationship with `options`.

My approach:

```py
    class Option(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        price = models.FloatField()
    class Order(models.Model):
        option = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)

        def get_price(self):
            price = None
            if self.option:
                price = self.option.price
            return price
```

this hits an error and says `many related model has no attribute price`.

Comment: A `ManyToManyField` means that an order can have *zero*, *one* or *more* `Option`s, so `self.option.price` does not make much sense, since a *collection* of `Option`s has no `price`.

Comment: the prices of the options can be 0 for n
so either you want the highest, average or the whole array of prices.
Kindly clarify this so we can help you